# How to create an hour based scheduling app in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, calendar, schedule

Typical calendars involve adding events simply based by date.  Each event is usually just listed per the day they are attached.

What I am working on is a scheduling app that is based on hour blocks in a day.  So, a person might be able to schedule a conference room from 08:00 to 12:00.  Users would be able to view today, or any other day...which would show what events are scheduled for the viewed day and show them as blocks of reserved hours.

I need to somehow display the schedule in an html table.  The part I'm struggling with is that the start_time and end_time will need to flow vertically across table rows in the same column (see image).

Also, the owner of the schedule can set their hours of operation.  So, if their doors open at 09:00 and they close at 17:00, then those are the times (in 15 minute increments) that will be listed down the left side of the table.  And, the custom "events" that are schedule will be the columns across the table head.

The image should show you what I am trying to create.  The hitch is, saving a record in the Schedule model that includes who scheduled it, the day the reservation is for, and the start and end times of that reservation...and then, somehow add css classes to appropriate td and tr to display that reservation in the table.

Any ideas, suggestions, or gems that already exist would be much appreciated!

I'm using rails 3, ruby 2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay best way to do this would be to create a DateTime object in your controller that handles this. Then you can loop over the time and have this output what you expect you can also loop over the events so that it generates the number of cells for what you need. The next thing you would have to do after you have done all of this is add the jQuery dialog to the cell so that each individual cell is uniquely identifiable. From this you will then most probably want to render a partial inside the dialog so that the administrator can create these schedules. You will need to use the HTML5 data-attribute on the `<td>` so that you can pass this data into the application. I have provided some starting code for you to work with below as a starting point.

**view**

```
<table class ="time_events">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="time">Time</th>
      <% @events.each do |eve| %>
        <th class="events-<%= eve.name %>"></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
    <% @time_range.each do |time| %> 
      <tr>
        <th>
          <%=time.to_formatted_s(:short)%>
        </th> 
        <% @events.each do |events| %> 
          <td class=time_slot> 
            <!--Do some more stuff here --> 
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

As mentioned earlier you may want to go with setting jQuery dialog on the cells so that when you click the cell the dialog appears. With this you could do something like this in you `application.js`

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.time_events td').live('click', function (event) {

        var $target = $(this);
        // variable target find the class schedule 
        var $bf = $target.find('.event_form');
        //data of event_id is accessed by the .data() function
        var event = $target.data('event-id');

        $bf.dialog();
        //find the input value of the event_id.
        //Referenced via data-attributes.
        $bf.find('input#event_id').val(event);

        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.event_form.user_full_name').on('change', function (e) {
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

**controller**

```
def index 

  @events = Event.all 

  @beginning_current = params[beginning_of_day].try(:to_time) || Time.now
  @time_range (@beginning_current.beginning_of_day..@beginning_current.end_of_day)

  respond_to do |format| 
   format.html
   format.json { render json: @events }

  end 
 end 
end
```

Quoting what you said:

> The hitch is, saving a record in the Schedule model that includes who
>   scheduled it, the day the reservation is for, and the start and end
>   times of that reservation.

As mentioned above you need to use the HTML5 data-attribute to pass this data to the application.js so that it can determine the which unique cell is being clicked. Alternative methods to doing what you want are to use [Ashraws calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) which has a full documentation support on tweaking it to your needs.